# Stop Processing For loop with User Input

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang. I am trying to provide an exit from processing of a long for loop in golang.  The for loop iterates through an array of over 700 items.  I would like to give the end user an option to click on X to break the loop.
I tried reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin),  but then it waits for input every time it enters the loop.  How do you determine if a user has had a keypress and exit the loop without pausing to wait for input each time?

Comment: Such cancellation is usually made possible by passing either a channel of type `chan struct{}` or a `context.Context` to your function. However, you should add [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we understand exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you are asking how to process a single key press, without pressing the enter key, you have to find a TTY library, because stdin is normally line-buffered by the terminal emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below to use goroutine and channel.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    stopCh := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if strings.TrimSpace(text) == "stop" {
            stopCh <- true
        }
    }()

loop:
    for {
        select {
        case stop := <-stopCh:
            if stop {
                break loop
            }
        default:
            // long processing

            time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        }

    }
}
```

Basically you create a new goroutine to take the input from user and then send it to the channel. In the main processing loop. you do a select which will poll the stop channel and see whether any stop command is given, if no, it goes to default and do the normal job you ask to do. Otherwise, if a stop command is received, it will break the for loop.